# Backbone.js: Raise model change event after fetching the collection?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a model with a name attribute that has a bind function to be called when the attribute is changed:

```js
var Workitem = Backbone.Model.extend({
                                 initialize: function(){
                                 this.bind('change:name', function() {
                                           alert('name');
                                           }
                                           });
                                 },
                                 defaults: {
                                 name: 'Name'
                                 }
                                 });
```

If I fetch a single model, this works, and the change event is triggered when I set the attribute and when I fetch the data.

But then I've created a collection and I want the event to be triggered for each fetched model into the collection during the fetch method:

```js
var WorkitemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                                       model: Workitem,
                                       });

var workitemsList = new WorkitemList();
workitemsList.fetch();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have url's set for the collection and model or do the values just magically appear from somewhere?

Comment: Hi Jakee, I'm using backbone.localStorage.js, so when I execute the fetch, the data is read from the HTML5 local storage, but I thought this wasn't relevant to my problem. When I do the same with a single model (stored in the localStorage), the change event is triggered after the fetch, but if the model is a collection item this is not working

Answer (score 1):

Fetch triggers 'reset' event on the collection when import is done. listen on it, fire / mess with models  then.

Answer (score 0):

fetching a collection replaces the models in the collection with the server response.. it doesn't update each of the models in the collection which is what you want.. The easiest fix would be to loop through the collection fetching each model but then you have multiple requests to the server and miss out on any newly added models..

I think for what you want to achieve you would need to create and fetch another instance of your collection and then compare the models in that with your original collection and update as needed.. not real pretty..

Comment: Hi Lecstor, thanks for your answer. I'm trying to loop to the model after the fetch() method to do your workaround but this is not working (alert is returning zero instead of the number of fetched items):
`var WorkitemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model : Workitem,
 initialize : function() {
  this.fetch({
   success : alert(this.length)
  });
 }
});`

Comment: I think that should be more like.. `var WorkitemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model : Workitem, initialize : function() { this.fetch({ success : function(collection, response){ alert(collection.length) }}); } });`

Answer (score 0):

You could override the collection's `fetch`-function to call fetch on each model individually. But that's very brute force.

```
fetch: function() {
  for (var model: this.models) {
    model.fetch();
  }
}
```

Anyone have a nicer way of accomplishing this?